# Mac OS X Cocoa multiview application navigation

Tags: cocoa, multiview, nsviewcontroller

I've already spent 2 full days trying to figure out how to use NSViewControllers in order to create a multiview application.

Here is what I do.

I have 2 View Controllers and the MainMenu.xib's Window.
I also have an AppController that is the delegate for both View Controllers.

When I launch the app, I'm first greeted with the MainMenu.xib's Window's view which holds a button. On clicking this button, an IBAction is sent to the appController and asks for the SecondViewController to display it's nib. So far, everything's fine and the nib file is displayed correctly.

On the secondViewController, there's another button that sends another IBAction to the appController and asks for the FirstViewController to be displayed but nothing happens,
no crash, no warning... Any help would be much appreciated...
Thanks in advance for your patience...

Here is the code for the AppController.h :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface AppController : NSObject

@property (strong) IBOutlet NSWindow *mainWindow;

@property (strong) IBOutlet SecondViewController *secondViewController;
@property (strong) IBOutlet FirstViewController *firstViewController;


- (IBAction)secondButtonfromsecondViewControllerClicked:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender;

@end
```

and here is the code for the AppController.m :

```
#import "AppController.h"


@implementation AppController
@synthesize mainWindow = mainwindow;
@synthesize secondViewController;
@synthesize firstViewController;

- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {

     NSLog(@"button from second View Controller clicked");

     self.secondViewController = [[SecondViewController  
     alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
     self.mainWindow.contentView = self.secondViewController.view;
     [self.secondViewController.view setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable | 
     NSViewHeightSizable];
}

 - (IBAction)secondButtonfromsecondViewControllerClicked:(id)sender {

     NSLog(@"button from first ViewController clicked");

     self.firstViewController = [[FirstViewController 
     alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
     self.mainWindow.contentView = [self.firstViewController view];

}


@end
```

Well, anyone can help me, I just need a single view application that displays a first ViewController with a button on the first viewController that takes me to a second view controller with a second button that takes me back to my first viewcontroller... I've already spent more than a week on that... in vain... PS : I don't want any button on the mainMenu.xib window nor tabs.

Comment: Any particular reason that you want to use a view controller (apart from maybe being used to using them in iOS)? It sounds like a perfect job for a tab view. Or even just swapping views programmatically.

Comment: OK, and you've checked the obvious; the action is not connected within Interface Builder?

Comment: Waouh, at least some answers ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is the solution to my question then.

Here's the code for the AppDelegate.h:

```
  //  AppDelegate.h


 #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
 #import "FirstViewController.h"
 #import "SecondViewController.h"

 //We need to declare the AppDelegate class as being the delegate for both 
 //FirstViewController and SecondViewController

 @interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, 
 FirstViewControllerDelegate, SecondViewControllerDelegate>

 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSWindow *window;
 @property (strong) FirstViewController *firstViewController;
 @property (strong) SecondViewController *secondViewController;

 -(void) goToSecondView;
 -(void) goToFirstView;

 @end
```

Now, here's the AppDelegate.m:

```
 //  AppDelegate.m

 #import "AppDelegate.h"


 @implementation AppDelegate

 @synthesize window = _window;
 @synthesize firstViewController;
 @synthesize secondViewController;

 -(void) awakeFromNib {

 [self goToFirstView];
 self.firstViewController.delegate = self;

 }


 -(void) goToSecondView {

        if (self.secondViewController ==nil) {
            self.secondViewController =[[SecondViewController alloc] 
            initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
        }

        self.window.contentView = [self.secondViewController view];
  }

 -(void) goToFirstView {

 if (self.firstViewController ==nil) {
     self.firstViewController =[[FirstViewController alloc] 
     initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
   }

    self.window.contentView = [self.firstViewController view];

 }

 @end
```

Next we need to set delegates in the FirstViewController and the SecondViewController

```
//  FirstViewController.h

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "SecondViewController.h"

//We declare the delegation protocole:

@protocol FirstViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)goToSecondView;

@end

@interface FirstViewController : NSViewController

- (IBAction)firstViewControllerButtonClicked:(id)sender;

@property (nonatomic, strong) id <FirstViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

And here is the FirstViewController.m:

```
 //  FirstViewController.m

 #import "FirstViewController.h"

 @implementation FirstViewController
 @synthesize delegate;

 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil{
   self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
   if (self) {

    self.delegate = [NSApp delegate];

    }

   return self;
 }

 - (IBAction)firstViewControllerButtonClicked:(id)sender {

   NSLog(@"button from first View Controller clicked");

   if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(goToSecondView)]) {
    [self.delegate goToSecondView];
   }
 }

 @end
```

Now, same thing for the SecondViewController:

```
 //  SecondViewController.h

 #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

 @protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

 -(void)goToFirstView;

 @end

 @interface SecondViewController : NSViewController

 @property (nonatomic, strong) id <SecondViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

 - (IBAction)goToFirstViewControllerButtonClicked:(id)sender;

 @end
```

And here's the SecondViewController.m:

```
  //  SecondViewController.m

  #import "SecondViewController.h"

  @interface SecondViewController ()

  @end

  @implementation SecondViewController

  - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil{
  self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
  if (self) {

      self.delegate = [NSApp delegate];
   }

    return self;
  }

  - (IBAction)goToFirstViewControllerButtonClicked:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"button from Second View Controller clicked");

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(goToFirstView)]) {
    [self.delegate goToFirstView];
  }

 }
 @end
```

Well, I guess this code may be improved and if you have any suggestion, feel free to let me know. Hope it will help others.

Answer (score 1):

**THE PROBLEM:**  When the user presses a button in View2, you want View1 to appear. It's not.

STEP 1: You say that the button *should* be invoking an action on your AppController.  Set a breakpoint (or add a diagnostic log) in that action, just to verify that it is, in fact, being invoked.

STEP 2: Think about what you want that action to do, precisely.  My guess is that you want to hide View2 and show View1. Perhaps

```
 [view2 setHidden: YES];
 [view1 setHidden: NO];
```

(I'm not using your names here, of course.)  Or you might animate the transitions, either cross-fading the views or moving them.

STEP 3: My guess is that STEP 2 will solve your problem. If it doesn't, use the debugger again to verify that view1 and view2 are not null. (If they're null, you probably have weak variables where you need them to be strong.)

STEP 4: In the unlikely event that you're still stuck, check the frames of view1 and view2. Perhaps view1 isn't where you think it is.

STEP 5:  If you're still stuck, check the alphaValue of view1. Maybe you set it to be transparent, and it's being drawn transparently in the right place.

STEP 6: I bet there is no step 6!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but that's not what I wanted to do. I have found a way to implement what I wanted to do using delegates that make the Appdelegate load the ViewControllers. The fact is that I had not coded anything in three years so it took me some time to implement it. After reading some more, it's working at last ! Thanks to all of you guys anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't much of an answer at the moment, however I have some concerns about your code that I wanted to work through with you.

- Are you sure you have connected the outlets and actions in Interface Builder.  Please verify this.
- You don't need `mainWindow` as there is already a `window` property that points to the main window (verify this in Interface Builder).  Also this looks wrong:

  ```
  @synthesize mainWindow = mainwindow;
                               ^
                               W
  ```

  So dump that and just use the existing `window` outlet provided by Xcode.
- Don't re-create the view controllers if they already exist:

  ```
  if (self.secondViewController == nil)
  {
      self.secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController"
                                                                         bundle:nil];
  }
  self.window.contentView = self.secondViewController.view;
  ```

Comment: The reason why I want to use ViewControllers is that I want to port my Iphone app to the Mac, and I want to use a different views for each task. The real question is How can I navigate between the ViewControllers and load their views inside the MainMenu.xib's window's contentview programmatically from inside the code of my viewcontrollers ? On IOS, I had a RootViewController and a navigation controller but there's no navigation controller for MAC... Moreover, I haven't coded a single line in three years so I'm not even sure I know what to link inside IB.

Comment: If I remove the mainWindow property inside the AppController class, I don't know how to call the mainMenu.xib's window's contentView from the AppController. I don't understand "You don't need mainWindow as there is already a window property that points to the main window". When I had the mainWindow property inside the appController, I could use it to display the first viewController, now I'm at a loss without that property. Should I use super ? The problem seems to be with the mainWindow whose value is 00000 in step-by-step debug mode.

Comment: You should use `self.window` now, rather than `self.mainWindow`.

Comment: Property 'window' not found on object type 'AppController'

Comment: That doesn't sound right.  My understanding was the Xcode generated a app with a `window` property.  Can you verify in IB by right-clicking on the window in the left-hand pane and seeing if it's connected to anything.  Otherwise you might have to put back your `mainWindow` connection and ignore me.

Comment: It only has its delegate set to the AppController class

Comment: Hmmm, OK you'll have to put back your `mainWindow` connection; sorry.

Comment: the window property exists in the AppDelegate CLass of my app but not in the AppController class.

Comment: Hummmmm, well, I want to have something like a rootViewController for IOS, hence the AppController Class. Is it mandatory to have all the app's code into the AppDelegate class ? And if so, how can I call the AppDelegate's window property from my AppController class ?

Comment: No, you can put the code where you like.  However it doesn't sound the AppController is anything like the root view controller in this case.  Perhaps using a window controller would be closer.  But I think you will need to let go of trying to make your Mac app structure the same as an iOS app; they are different so just accept the differences.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24768/discussion-between-miky-mike-and-trojanfoe)